# Amazon, AWS - What is a remap and how to calculate the costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-ip

i got the first report for my account activity. the costs for remapping the elastic ip are quite expensive in relation to the cpu hours.

- my instance is running from 8 to 21 from monday to friday and from 8 to 9 on saturday and sunday.
- the start script at 8 associates an elastic ip.

could anyone please explain me how to calculate the total amount of remaps that are charged? i hope my explanation is sufficient if not pls ask.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you will be charged for each hour the IP is NOT allocated to an instance.  In this case, add up the hours:
46 hrs (23 hrs x2) from 9am Sat/Sun - 8am Sun/Mon,
55 hrs (11 hrs x5) from 9pm - 8am T,W,Th,Fr,Sa

So, per week you'll be charged 101 hrs for the time the elastic IP is unassigned.

Edit: I see you are actually asking about remapping.  Well, assuming you're talking about a single instance and a single IP, you're basically looking at

$0.10 per Elastic IP address remap – additional remap / month over 100

In your case, it looks like you are doing 1 remap per day, so I'm not even clear how you're being charged.  Being that these are reported in the same area, is it possible the charges are actually from the unassigned time on the IP?

Comment: i have 5 free EIPs per account - does it mean i can do 500 free remaps?

Comment: @AlexB I believe the answer is no. Amazon's wording is *$0.00 per Elastic IP address remap for the first 100 remaps per month* with no mention of the total number of elastic IPs you hold. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/